# Beautifull Soup to scraping web page all the odds table

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the tables from the URL webpage using the following code.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = [
'https://g10oal.com/match/c81e21f3-7804-4961-ac74-4e2804a19784/odds'
]


all_data = []
for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    table = soup.findAll("class", {"class":"table table-sm  odds-compare-table"})[0]

    # here I store all rows to list `all_data`
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        tds = [cell.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for cell in row.findAll(["td",      "th"])]
        all_data.append(tds)
        print(*tds)

# write list `all_data` to CSV
with open("c:/logs/test.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

After running the code, it shown "IndexError: list index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `argument` of `findAll` is the `name` of the tag/element, not an `attribute`.

You should do

```py
# make sure to use a single space only between table-sm and odds-compare-table
tables = soup.findAll("table", {"class": "table table-sm odds-compare-table"})

# or, pass the classes as list
tables = soup.findAll("table", {"class": ["table", "table-sm", "odds-compare-table"]})
```

Then you loop on `tables`

```py
for table in tables:
  # here I store all rows to list `all_data`
  for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    tds = [cell.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"])]
    all_data.append(tds)
    print(*tds)
```

If you only want the first `table` you could use `find` instead of `findAll`

```py
table = soup.find("table", {"class": ["table", "table-sm", "odds-compare-table"]})
```